# Bootstrap modal login

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this website that is almost a 100% complete but it is based on a customized bootstrap 2.X to meet my needs (bad practice, the fault is entirely on my end.) and what I would like to do is to come up with a modal login that looks like this:

[**DEMO**](http://www.creative-tim.com/product/login-and-register-modal)

The live preview above is based on bootstrap 3.X

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cp67J/1598/)

```
 <a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="/mmfansler/aQ3Ge/show/">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>

    <div style="margin-left:35%;>
  <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </modal>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This one:

```
$(function() {

    var $formLogin = $('#login-form');
    var $formLost = $('#lost-form');
    var $formRegister = $('#register-form');
    var $divForms = $('#div-forms');
    var $modalAnimateTime = 300;
    var $msgAnimateTime = 150;
    var $msgShowTime = 2000;

    $("form").submit(function () {
        switch(this.id) {
            case "login-form":
                var $lg_username=$('#login_username').val();
                var $lg_password=$('#login_password').val();
                if ($lg_username == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Login error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Login OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            case "lost-form":
                var $ls_email=$('#lost_email').val();
                if ($ls_email == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Send error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Send OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            case "register-form":
                var $rg_username=$('#register_username').val();
                var $rg_email=$('#register_email').val();
                var $rg_password=$('#register_password').val();
                if ($rg_username == "ERROR") {
                    msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Register error");
                } else {
                    msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Register OK");
                }
                return false;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#login_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formRegister) });
    $('#register_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLogin); });
    $('#login_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formLost); });
    $('#lost_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formLogin); });
    $('#lost_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formRegister); });
    $('#register_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLost); });

    function modalAnimate ($oldForm, $newForm) {
        var $oldH = $oldForm.height();
        var $newH = $newForm.height();
        $divForms.css("height",$oldH);
        $oldForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime, function(){
            $divForms.animate({height: $newH}, $modalAnimateTime, function(){
                $newForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime);
            });
        });
    }

    function msgFade ($msgId, $msgText) {
        $msgId.fadeOut($msgAnimateTime, function() {
            $(this).text($msgText).fadeIn($msgAnimateTime);
        });
    }

    function msgChange($divTag, $iconTag, $textTag, $divClass, $iconClass, $msgText) {
        var $msgOld = $divTag.text();
        msgFade($textTag, $msgText);
        $divTag.addClass($divClass);
        $iconTag.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
        $iconTag.addClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
        setTimeout(function() {
            msgFade($textTag, $msgOld);
            $divTag.removeClass($divClass);
            $iconTag.addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
            $iconTag.removeClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
        }, $msgShowTime);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-login-with-jquery-effects)

[More Demos](http://bootsnipp.com/tags/modal?page=1)